# Format currency without currency symbol

Tags: java, currency, number-formatting

I am using `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(myLocale)` to get a custom currency format for a locale given by me. However, this always includes the currency symbol which I don't want, I just want the proper currency number format for my given locale without the currency symbol.

Doing a `format.setCurrencySymbol(null)` throws an exception..

Comment: Have you tried `.setCurrencySymbol("")`?

Comment: @home: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html

Comment: When there is no need for the currency, why not using `NumberFormat#getInstance( Locale )` ?

Comment: @home I was confused to.... 
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

Comment: @home, the result is different. Example: when you use NumberFormat.getInstance(), the result could be "1,200", but when you use NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(), the result is "1,200.00"

Comment: For example, Swiss Francs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/currency-formatting

_Most currencies use the same decimal and thousands separator that the numbers in the locale use, but this is not always true. In some places in Switzerland, they use the period as a decimal separator for Swiss frans (Sfr. 127.54), but then use commas as the decimal separator everywhere else (127,54)_

Comment: You should use the response described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54439986/9114314

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The following works. It's a bit ugly, but it fulfils the contract:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = ((DecimalFormat) nf).getDecimalFormatSymbols();
decimalFormatSymbols.setCurrencySymbol("");
((DecimalFormat) nf).setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
System.out.println(nf.format(12345.124).trim());
```

You could also get the pattern from the currency format, remove the currency symbol, and reconstruct a new format from the new pattern:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String pattern = ((DecimalFormat) nf).toPattern();
String newPattern = pattern.replace("\u00A4", "").trim();
NumberFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat(newPattern);
System.out.println(newFormat.format(12345.124));
```

Comment: Until you use negative amounts, then it shows the Symbol again. I'm sure that must be a bug.

Comment: To fix the negative showing the currency, you can add the line:

`((DecimalFormat) nf).setNegativePrefix(""+decimalFormatSymbols.getMinusSign());`

Comment: pattern.replace("\u00A4", "").trim()  <-- This trim doesn't work because Java uses non-breaking space \u00A0 which is not removed by this method.

Comment: Nice Answer @ JB

Answer (score 51):

Set it with an empty string instead:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setCurrencySymbol(""); // Don't use null.
formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
System.out.println(formatter.format(12.3456)); // 12.35
```

Comment: this is equally right as well though can only chose one answer as the right one..

Comment: I think the point is what Robin wrote: There is no need for  `getCurrencyInstance`, just use `getNumberInstance`

Comment: I think you might also need to set `formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);` in your second example.

Comment: @JoshDM: you shouldn't hardcode "2" here, unless you know you always want US Dollars, as the number of decimal points in currencies vary.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I certainly can hardcode it in a 5-year old comment; I leave it up to the original requester to design a dynamic approach to setting the variable based on required Locale.

Comment: _I think the point is what Robin wrote: There is no need for getCurrencyInstance, just use getNumberInstance_. Not true. See my comment on the OP.

Answer (score 9):

Just use `NumberFormat.getInstance()` instead of `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` like follows:

```
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance().apply {
    this.currency = Currency.getInstance()
}

val formattedText = numberFormat.format(3.4)
```

Comment: This returns a value #.# whereas getCurrencyInstance() returns #.##

Answer (score 7):

The given solution worked but ended up lefting some whitespaces for Euro for example.
I ended up doing :

```
numberFormat.format(myNumber).replaceAll("[^0123456789.,]","");
```

This makes sure we have the currency formatting for a number without the currency or any other symbol.

Comment: Love me some regex. Good solution using something simple like replaceAll while still being able to account for multiple formats

Comment: You might want to keep the minus sign (and also parenthesis)  for negative numbers.  `currencyString.replaceAll("[^0123456789.,()-]","")`

Comment: also some languages use an apostrophe (U+0027 or U+2019) as the thousands separator.
So you might want to do `currencyString.replaceAll("[^0123456789.,\(\)\-\x{0027}\x{2019}]","")`

Answer (score 4):

I still see people answering this question in 2020, so why not

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2); // <- the trick is here
System.out.println(nf.format(1000)); // <- 1,000.00
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we can just use replace or substring to just take the number part of the formatted string.

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
fmt.format(-1989.64).replace(fmt.getCurrency().getSymbol(), "");
//fmt.format(1989.64).substring(1);  //this doesn't work for negative number since its format is -$1989.64
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
String formatted = df.format(num);
```

Works with many types for `num`, but don't forget to [represent currency with BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

For the situations when your `num` can have more than two digits after the decimal point, you could use `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2)` to show only two, but that could only hide an underlying problem from whoever is running the application.

Answer (score 2):

Most (all?) solutions provided here are useless in newer Java versions. Please use this:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("hr"));
formatter.setNegativeSuffix(""); // does the trick
formatter.setPositiveSuffix(""); // does the trick

formatter.format(new BigDecimal("12345.12"))
```

Comment: this also removes the minus sign for negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

Two Line answer

```
NumberFormat formatCurrency = new NumberFormat.currency(symbol: "");
var currencyConverted = formatCurrency.format(money);
```

In TextView

```
new Text('${formatCurrency.format(money}'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormat numberFormat  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
        System.out.println("getCurrency = " + numberFormat.getCurrency());
        String number = numberFormat.format(99.123452323232323232323232);
        System.out.println("number = " + number);
```

Comment: try to explain your solution a bit, what was wrong in users code and what did you do to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

here the code that with any symbol (m2, currency, kilos, etc)

```
fun EditText.addCurrencyFormatter(symbol: String) {

   this.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {

        private var current = ""

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            if (s.toString() != current) {
                this@addCurrencyFormatter.removeTextChangedListener(this)

                val cleanString = s.toString().replace("\\D".toRegex(), "")
                val parsed = if (cleanString.isBlank()) 0.0 else cleanString.toInt()

                val formatter = DecimalFormat.getInstance()

                val formated = formatter.format(parsed).replace(",",".")

                current = formated
                this@addCurrencyFormatter.setText(formated + " $symbol")
                this@addCurrencyFormatter.setSelection(formated.length)

                this@addCurrencyFormatter.addTextChangedListener(this)
            }
        }
    })

}
```

-use with-

```
edit_text.addCurrencyFormatter("TL")
```

Answer (score 0):

In a function like this

```
 fun formatWithoutCurrency(value: Any): String {
    val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance()
    return numberFormat.format(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for me. It shows it hardcoded for one locale, but you could pass in any locale as as both NumberFormat constructors use the same locale (and `currency`):

```
const locale = 'en-US';
const currency = 'USD';

const getCurrencySymbol = () =>
  (0)
    .toLocaleString(locale, {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: currency,
      maximumFractionDigits: 0,
      minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    })
    .replace(/\d/g, '')
    .trim();

const formattedNumberWithoutSymbol = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: currency,
}).format(499.99).replace(getCurrencySymbol(), '');

console.log(formattedNumberWithoutSymbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cleaner solution that doesn't alter the currency symbol in a hacky way:

```
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().apply {
    val priceFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
    minimumFractionDigits = priceFormat.minimumFractionDigits
    maximumFractionDigits = priceFormat.maximumFractionDigits
}
```

For some reason, setting the currency in NumberFormat with `Currency.getInstance()` didn't work for me.

Answer (score -2):

there is **a need** for a currency format "WITHOUT the symbol", when u got huge reports or views and almost all columns represent monetary values, the symbol is annoying, there is no need for the symbol but yes for thousands separator and decimal comma.
U need

```
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
```

and not

```
new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00");
```

Comment: This is only helpful if the Locale is US, Canada, Australia, etc. It does not work for Sterling or Euro (where some countries use decimal points instead of commas for the thousand separator).

Comment: The post is not about using period or commas as thousand separators, u are off topic

Comment: I still get for  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");  Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "$400.00"

Answer (score -2):

Please try below:

```
var totale=64000.15
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE');
totaleGT=new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE' ).format(totale)
```