# Apply formatting to variables in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, int

Is there a simple way to format variables on a GUI with spaces (or commas) between so its easier to read.

Example:

```
int x = 12000000;

JLabel.setText(x);
```

which outputs `1200000`, however I am trying to achieve on of the following.

- `1 200 000`
- `1,200,000`

Comment: And also [Format currency without currency symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658205/format-currency-without-currency-symbol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
int x = 12000000;
JLabel.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the user's locale to determine whether to use commas or decimal points, use the following:

```
String formattedNum = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(x);
```

For Americans, you would see `1,200,000`.