# How to format a BigDecimal as currency without symbol in Play Framework (or Java)?

Tags: java, playframework, currency-formatting

I want to format a BigDecimal as a currency in one Locale but use the currency symbol of another. In this particular case it's a Swedish user but the amount is in Euro.

My hope is that you can show me a better way than this:

```
public String getFormattedAmount()
{
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale(currentUser.getLocale()));
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = ((DecimalFormat) nf).getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    decimalFormatSymbols.setCurrencySymbol("");
    ((DecimalFormat) nf).setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
    return nf.format(amount).trim();
}
```

Play 2.2.

Comment: Dear Close voters,

The similar question has nothing to do with Play Framework. Play's former template language had `${ 42.formatCurrency('EUR').raw() }` but I can't seem to find anything similar in the current one. I figured it might still be there even though I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution (inspired in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658385/1426227)):

```
DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale(currentUser.getLocale()));
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
String formattedValue = nf.format(amout);
```

Comment: That wouldn't handle the currency thousands separator.

Comment: What locale are you using? Please, show me an example.

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your question, but formatting `123456789` using `new Locale("sv", "SE")` with your code and mine, I always get `123 456 789,00`. Is it correct?

Comment: That would be correct for decimal values but for currency amounts it should be 123.456.789,00.

Comment: You know about Swedish currency formatting better than me, but the code `DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("sv", "SE")).format(123456789)` produces `123 456 789,00 kr`. For Java, the decimal separator is a space and not a dot.

Comment: That's strange. `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` produces `123.456.789,00`.

Comment: Did you try with Swedish locale?

Comment: Yes but my question wasn't to get it working. My code above works. I just hoped there was an easier solution.

Comment: I thought my solution would work. I just got curious about the differences on the formatting. I tried the same code on Java 7 and Java 8 and I always get a space instead of a dot.