# JSP money formatting

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to format money for Swiss locale, and my company needs it formated like this:

> 9'949.50
>
> -191'565.10

But when I apply following code in JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<fmt:setLocale value="de_CH" scope="session"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${value}" type="currency" />
```

I get ok money formatting but it adds currency code, which we don't want. So this is result:

> SFr. 9'949.50
>
> SFr. -191'565.10

Is there a way to turn off currency code display? I tried in various ways but all I get is exceptions.

Edit: as pointed in comments, this is JSP related question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format currency without currency symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658205/format-currency-without-currency-symbol)

Comment: @Bill this is more of a JSP question, not really a JAVA question. So I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: check out.  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html   The HaRLoFei answer below looks correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure whether it'll help or not. Can you please try add currencySymbol attribute with empty string as value? Like below:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${value}" type="currency" currencySymbol=""/>
```

Comment: I swear I tried this, but don't how it didn't work then :) Anyway, now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Best Number format in my humble opinion  is big decimal format , however modern frame work such spring or Jsf has conversion formatter support see  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html using spring tag will automatically format in client side  ,But  for pure jsp It is best to use jsp beans:

```
    public class Formatter implements java.io.Serializable
{
   private String currency= null;

   public String getCurrency(){
      return [format here];
   }

   //setter
}
```

and in jsp use

```
   <jsp:useBean id="cid" class="Formatter" >
   <jsp:setProperty name="cid" property="currency"  
                    value="value"/>
   <jsp:getProperty name="cid" property="currency"/>
    ...........
   </jsp:useBean>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set value="20014825.50" var="val" scope="request"/>
<fmt:setLocale value="de_CH"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${val}" minFractionDigits="2"/>
```